# why mocha doesn't show passed tests ? like jest. it just says 5 test passed not more details

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I am new to mocha but experienced in jest. so when I run my test I hope it should display a complete log. but it just says 9 test passed. I am using nyan reporter

here is a screen shot
[image]

Comment: Which [reporter](https://mochajs.org/#reporters) have you set ?

Comment: I am using nyan reporter

Comment: You could change to an other reporter, like "spec", or try changing your config. The  "nyan" reporter inherits the base reporter interface : https://mochajs.org/api/mocha.reporters.base

Comment: how can i change my config

Comment: Don't you have a config file ? Are you using the command line only ? If so please include the command in your question. But anyway, I would suggest using an other reporter than the nyan reporter (the spec reporter is fine).

Comment: I am using a config file for running node.js but not have a config file for testing

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using mochawesome reporter and utilizing a .mocharc.js file or .mocharc.json file for your configurations unless you want to run mocha programmatically

Comment: that command looks correct you can also set all these configurations within a .mocharc.js file and export it. also you can set the name to something else if you want with the reporter flag.